# Want to load just the single csproj file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a solution file with 3 projects under it. A situation came up where I need to open just the one csproj file in the solution. So I tried to open just that single csproj file.

Guess what wonderful Visual Studio does. It **always** opens the entire associated solution of the csproj file! I've tried double-clicking on the csproj file from Windows Explorer, tried File->Open->Project/Solution and *explicitly* chose the csproj file, all to no avail.

This is where I have to say the eggheads at Microsoft are so smart that they are stupid. Does anyone have an idea what I can do, short of creating **another** solution (containing only the one csproj file that I want)?

Comment: Just goes to show that simple and classic things work better than stupid ideas like `over-engineering`, `eat-your-own-dogfood`, and other misguided and painfully over-thought-out ideas.

Comment: How about just temporarily unloading (but not removing) the other two projects in the main solution.

Comment: I just ended up making a blank solution to hold the one project that I wanted. But still, I wonder if there could be a better way.